# How to list the index of all consecutive and single values in a row in R matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, match

I have an `xlsx` file containing some cells with value -3. Some are single cells and some are consecutive cells with -3 value. I am trying to write a `R` script, which finds the index of these cells containing -3, such that for single cell -3 values I get the single index and for consecutive cell -3 values I get the starting and the ending index.

Here is `matrix` from the `xlsx` file with 20 `columns` and 2 `rows`

```
3.203   3.204   3.205   -3  3.207   3.207   -3  -3  -3  3.206   3.208   3.207   -3  3.264   3.207   3.208   -3  -3  3.209   -3
3.205   3.205   3.205   3.21    3.208   3.208   3.209   -3  -3  3.209   3.211   3.21    3.211   3.211   3.21    -3  3.213   3.211   3.212   3.212
```

I want the result to look something like this (I have treated -3 as a missing value). So,

```
1  missing value at: ( 1 , 4 ) 
3  missing values starting from: ( 1 , 7 ) to ( 1 , 9 )
1  missing value at ( 1 , 13 ) 
2  missing values starting from: ( 1 , 17) to ( 1 , 18 )  
1  missing value at: ( 1, 20 ) 
2  missing values starting from: ( 2 , 8 ) to ( 2 , 9 )
1  missing value at: ( 2, 16 )
```

Here is the R script, but it is giving me wrong results. I am very confused with the right use of indexes.

```
fileData <- read.xlsx(filePath, 1, header = FALSE, sep = ",")
dataMatrix <- data.matrix(fileData)

## Find the number of rows and columns in the matrix
numberOfRows <- nrow(dataMatrix)
numberOfColumns <- ncol(dataMatrix)

## Access each value of the dataMatrix, check if it -3
  for (i in 1:numberOfRows)  # for each row
  {
    # Get indexes for -3 value
    missingValueList = which(dataMatrix[i,] == -3); 
    # Find the index after which there is a break (so no consecutive value)
    consecutiveBreaks = which(diff(missingValueList) != 1);
    print(missingValueList)
    print(consecutiveBreaks)

    j=0;

    for(k in 1:length(consecutiveBreaks))
    {
      if(k == 1)
      {
        cat(consecutiveBreaks[k], " missing value at: (",i,",",missingValueList[j+k],")","\n");
      }
      else
      {
        cat("Value of k: ", k, "\n");
        cat(abs(consecutiveBreaks[k]-consecutiveBreaks[k-1]), " missing values starting from: (",i,",",missingValueList[j],")","\n");

      }
      j=j+1;
    }
  }
```

Can someone please help me to get the desired solution?

Comment: What is the motivation for this? Depending on what you intend to do with the indices, there is likely a better approach.

Comment: @BryanGoggin The main aim is to replace the -3 cells with some value. In the case of since cell -3 index, I want to replace the -3 with the mean of the neighbouring two cell values. When the -3 values are consecutive for multiple cells, I want to take the mean of the adjoining values, replace it in the first -3 cell, take the mean of this new value with the adjoining value and replace in the next -3 cell and like wise.

Comment: you are complicating this code by using indexes. You should use loops and iterate over every missing values and simultaneously replace them with the means.

Comment: @JstRoRR I tried doing that, but I get messed up with the loop for consecutive -3 values. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I think this should work with your data:

```
val = 1;
counter = 1;
temp = matrix();

for (i in 1:nrow(mdata))
{
  for (j in 1:ncol(mdata))
  {
  if (mdata[i,j] == -3)
  {

    while (j <= ncol(mdata))
    {
      if (mdata[i,j + val] == -3)
      {
        counter = counter + 1;
        val = val + 1;
        next;                    
      }
      else
      {
        break;

      }

    }

    if (counter == 1)
    {
      #print(j);
      #print(mdata[i, (j - 1):(j + 1)]);

      temp <- t(as.matrix(mdata[i, (j - 1):(j + 1)]))
      cat("\n This is with counter 1 \n")
      print(temp)
      cat("\n matrix: temp-1", temp[,1],"temp-2", temp[,3],"\n");
      to.avg <- c(temp[,1], temp[,3]);
      avg<-mean(to.avg)
      mdata[i,j] = avg;
    }
    else
    {

      temp <- t(as.matrix(mdata[i,(j - 1):(j + counter)]))
      cat("\n This is with multiple count \n")
      cat(counter,"consecutive values were found, processing accordingly \n")
      print(temp);

      for (k in 0:(counter-1))
      {
        # cat("\n reading temp at the start \n")
        # print(temp)
        cat("\n K is ",(k+1), "and array is",length(temp),"long \n")
        to.avg <- c(temp[,(k+1)], temp[,length(temp)]);
        cat("averaging", temp[,(k+1)],"and", temp[,length(temp)]);
        avg<-mean(to.avg)
        cat("\n average =",avg);
        temp[,(k+2)] = avg;
        # cat("\n reading temp as this \n")
        # print(temp)
        mdata[i,j+k]=avg
      }

    }

  }
  else
  {
    mdata[i,j] = mdata[i,j];
  }

  val = 1;
  counter = 1;

  }

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was wanting to do. Works perfectly :)